# Can docker help me avoid the reinstallation process of libraries everytime I ssh to a new machine?

Tags: docker, ssh, dockerfile

I have a list of python libraries I need to reinstall everytime I ssh onto this new computer on campus. How can I make sure I only have to create one file/write one command so I don't have to repeat this reinstallation process? Is Docker a good way to do so?

I have a requirements.txt file with all libraries I need

1. pandas
2. matplotlib
3. seaborn
4. numpy
5. sklearn
6. opencv-python

The project has various Jupyter notebooks which require the above imports to run.

I'm not too familiar with Dockerfiles and Docker containers:

```
FROM my/base
ADD . /srv
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python sunflower.ipynb

ENTRYPOINT ["run_server"]
```

Would I wrap my entire project in a Dockerfile similar to that seen above? I have to ssh to a machine called dgx1.cc.gatech.edu by connecting a port on my machine to the corresponding port on the the dgx1.

```
8088:localhost:8088 username@dgx1.cc.gatech.edu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can run any Docker command, you can trivially get unrestricted root access to the entire system.  It's extremely unlikely that you'll be able to run Docker commands on shared systems like you describe.  Docker has several other disadvantages here and I wouldn't recommend it for the use case you're describing.

On the other hand, the Python `requirements.txt` file on its own is enough to list out the dependencies you need.  You can [create a virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) and install those packages into it, and they will be under your control and isolated from anything else installed on that system.  Using this just involves:

```sh
# Create the virtual environment
python3 -m venv ./sunflower

# Make it be your current Python ("activate" it)
. ./sunflower/bin/activate

# Install the packages you need
pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Run your script
python3 sunflower.ipynb

# Switch back to the system Python
deactivate
```

If you repeatedly ssh into the same system you can reuse the same virtual environment; re-run the `activate` command and the packages will be already installed.

(The current [official Python tooling recommendation](https://packaging.python.org/guides/tool-recommendations/) is to use [Pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) if you don't have more specialized needs, but that uses a different package-listing file setup than the `requirements.txt` file.)